# Java OSX APP Problems

Tags: java, macos

I am having problems with my java application after **Finally** figuring out how to use the app bundler to turn my project into a runnable .app on osx. I managed to get the bundler to package my single jar file along with the whole java 1.7 jdk. Here is my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <project basedir="." default="build" name="FT">
 <property environment="env"/>
 <taskdef
 name="bundleapp"
 classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"
 classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

 <target name="bundle">
     <bundleapp
         outputdirectory="dist"
         name="shareio"
         displayname="Shareio"
         identifier="com.example.shareio"
         shortversion="1.0"
         applicationCategory="public.app-category.developer-tools"
         mainclassname="Client">
         <classpath file="java/Shareio.jar"/>
         <runtime dir="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home" />
     </bundleapp>
 </target>
```

The problem that i am having is:

1. When i launch the newly created Shareio.app, the whole program looks blurry or fuzzy, sometimes it doesn't display or load the JTables or tabs inside my program. It almost seems like its not running it in the correct Java VM version.

I can launch the Shareio.jar file by itself (inside the shareio.app/Contents/java dir) and the program runs flawlessly and looks fine.

The project also launches completely fine through eclipse. I am using eclipse to export the project as shareio.jar. My project is build using java SE 7.

Am i missing something here? I cant seem to figure this one out. My macbook is running 10.9 and java versions: 1.6 and 1.7. java -version says 1.7 as well. Like i said, The program only has issues when i launch it as an app.

I can attach images if you would like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### 7.3.2 Property List Attributes for Java Applications

```
com.apple.macosx.AntiAliasedTextOn
```

> This property defaults to true. When rendering text, it tells the
>   application to use anti-aliasing. Occasionally you might want to
>   switch this value to false. If your application draws text to the same
>   location twice, it can look blurry, as each application of the text to
>   the screen is incrementally darker. Conversely, if your application
>   expects to erase text by drawing the background color over previously
>   rendered text, anti-aliasing artifacts can be left over. Under JDK
>   1.4.1, use apple.awt.textantialiasing instead (as described in the next section). Note that you can include both properties with no ill
>   effects.

```
com.apple.macosx.AntiAliasedGraphicsOn
```

> This property also defaults to true. Like the potential issues around
>   anti-aliased text, the default Mac OS X rendering of graphics can lead
>   to blurry graphics. You may see a small performance increase by
>   setting this property to false.

http://etutorials.org/Mac+OS/macos+x+for+java+geeks/Chapter+7.+Standalone+Applications/7.3+Application+Bundles/