# Create PNG without Text Anti-Aliasing in Java 11 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-11, graphics2d

When running the code below with Java 11 on Mac OS X the results differ from running it on Linux: The left side shows the output on Linux (no text anti-aliasing), the right side shows the output on Mac OS X (notable text anti-aliasing).

[image: Left: Output on Linux without anti-aliasing, Right: Output on Mac OS X with anti-aliasing]

Is there a way to disable the text anti-aliasing on Mac OS X?

Or, more generally, what is the recommended way to generate PNGs images with text and simple shapes using Java in an OS-independent, pixel-precise manner?

(Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html the recommended way seems to still be using `Graphics2D`, however that seems to lead to OS-dependent effects, e.g., the text anti-aliasing observed here).

The images above were created with the following sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Font font = loadFont();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(240, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    Graphics2D graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
    graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.clearRect(0, 0, 240, 60);
    graphics.setFont(font);
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.drawString("Hello, world!", 10, 50);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("test-" + System.getProperty("os.name") + ".png"));
}

private static Font loadFont() {
    try (InputStream stream = TestAntiAliasing.class.getResourceAsStream("/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf")) {
        return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 40);
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The code for Mac OS X was directly executed on Mac OS X Ventura 13.3.1 (a) with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7, mixed mode). The code for Linux was executed inside a Docker container with image eclipse-temurin:11 and OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.19+7 (build 11.0.19+7, mixed mode, sharing).

**Update**: It looks like this may be a known bug, see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8308148 Looking at the source of `SunGraphics2D` it seems there's an explicit override for Mac OS X, essentially forcing the anti-aliasing to be always on

```
    if (FontUtilities.isMacOSX14 &&
        (aahint == SunHints.INTVAL_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF))
    {
         aahint =  SunHints.INTVAL_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON;
    }
```

See https://github.com/adoptium/jdk11u/blob/jdk-11.0.19+7/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java#L774 This also does not seem to be fixed in more recent releases, e.g., https://github.com/adoptium/jdk11u/blob/jdk-11.0.20+4/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java#L774 or https://github.com/adoptium/jdk20u/blob/jdk-20.0.1%2B9/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java#L775

This means it may not be possible to use the approach for generating PNGs outlined above without text anti-aliasing (and by extension, that this is not a portable approach). Therefore, the question is whether there is an alternative approach that can be used to generate PNGs without text anti-aliasing that works in a portable (i.e., OS-independent) way?

Comment: Maybe you can try `System.setProperty("apple.awt.textantialiasing", "off")` on your Mac enviroment - or this answer maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592136/9434729

Comment: @Jelmen Unfortunately, setting the `apple.awt.textantialiasing` system property to `off` does not seem to have an effect. I found https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8308148 which seems to indicate that this is a known problem?

Comment: hm seems so - sorry that my hint did not work!

Comment: That bug support sounds discouraging. And I’m a bit surprised that there should be no way to render things without the operating system; I thought there was an integration of FreeType or similar library. But I suppose, when you create a `BufferedImage` with [`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_BINARY), i.e. 1 bit per pixel, they can’t create gray pixels at all. You can draw that 1 bit image over another true color image afterwards…